# Add image to Odoo survey

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-survey

How should I add an image field to an odoo survey?

In a survey I need the option to upload an image (or even more than one).

I found [this](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-can-i-add-images-in-odoo-surveys-110401), but I can't figure where or what.

Comment: Which version of odoo are you using ?

Comment: I'm using version 9

Comment: You cannot do this without customization. You can add a static image using the Website Designer but you cannot give the opportunity to the user to upload an image.

Comment: @GeorgeDaramouskas any directions on how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, we have to give the creator of the survey the opportunity to add a binary field to a survey page (used for the image upload)

Create a custom model that inherits from the `survey.question` model. Add a `('binary','Upload')` element in the state field.

Then on `addons/survey/views/survey_views.xml` find the [image: view] with the id `survey_question_form` and change it accordingly (for example when you add a question of type Binary you might want to hide some elements that refer to other types of questions)

After that go to `addons/survey/views/survey_templates.xml` and add a template:

```
<template id="binary_field" name="Image">
        <input type="image" class="form-control" t-att-name="prefix"/>
    </template>
```

Then, on the same file, find the template with the id = `page` and add

```
<t t-if="question.type == 'binary'"><t t-call="survey.binary_field"/></t>
```

Start testing the whole process by restarting your server with `-d your_database_name -u survey` and move from there.

More changes might be needed in addition to what I have mentioned.

Comment: Seems like a good solution, but I will need time to test it. +1

Comment: could you give some more details, i.e. can I extend the model by just going to Database structure->Models->Survey question and add a field here or should I do something else?